# Delegate Access and Subfolders

Tags: exchange-2013, delegation

Sometimes when a user leaves a company the manager will request access to the former employees mailbox on our Exchange 2013. I can use mailbox delegation to give them full access, but if there are any subfolders they don't see those. How can I on the Exchnage side set things so they can also see the subfolders in the mailbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Add-MailboxPermission`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124097(v=exchg.150).aspx) Powershell cmdlet to grant the "Full Mailbox Access" to the subject mailbox.

Alice has left the company. Bob needs access to her mailbox. The following command grants that access:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "Alice" -User "Bob" -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
```

Comment: Glad I could help.